# how to deploy an asp.net 3.5 project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows-server-2003

Which is the best way to deploy an asp .net 3.5 project?

I have a production server with IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.  I found that there are several to deploy it, but I think that xcopy deployment is OK for now.

However, I don't found the right to do it. Some tutorials suggest to create virtual directories, but I don't know where is the target

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more information you need than can be put in a simple answer, and this is borderline off-topic.

However, I do have a link for where you should start: [Deploying ASP.NET Applications in IIS 6.0 (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2f45f2ea-bcf8-4d23-9f15-5caf7ebdc2ef.mspx?mfr=true)

It's an older series of articles, but still applies.